# calculate time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I record the start time for a transaction in my database, and I have a time limit for each such transaction. I want to raise an alarm when it is timed out. Here are two ways I can think of doing this.

1) Let database do the calculation automatically so I can select records that exceed the limit.

2) Call the function from my script, give the current time, and calculate the time for each transaction in the database, then select aged ones.

I prefer the first solution, but I don't know how to do that. I am using Postgresql. Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use arithmetic operators with time values.  See here:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html

You can also make a literal value of "interval" type, which represents a start-time and duration (or start and stop times, depending how you prefer to think about it).

So you could do something like (not yet tested):

```
SELECT * FROM some_table 
WHERE timestamp_column - interval '1 hour' <= 0;
```

Comment: This is the second solution of mine, calculate for each one from the script. Is there a way that the database can automatically flag a record if it is timed out?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You can create triggers, but they only run on rows once you change something in them.  You can create stored procedures, but you still have to initiate those.  You could create a view, and that may be your best bet, but from a performance standpoint they're not really different from doing the query above, it's just that the restriction is hidden from view.  (Not my taste, personally - I like to keep that sort of logic in the app.)

Comment: @Michael You could wrap that in a view, eg CREATE VIEW some_stable_with_expires AS SELECT *, (timeout_column > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS is_expired FROM some_table;